# With htaccess, is it possible to rewrite every single url to one page?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/khp/handler.php
RewriteRule (.*) /khp/handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The desired result is for all urls, no matter whether or not they exist on the server, to be rewritten internally to `/khp/handler.php?url=$1`, where `$1` is the original url.

What is currently happening is when I go to a url that is the name of an existing folder, it does this: 
Requested url: `example.com/khp` 
Redirects to: `example.com/khp/?url=`

Ideally, it would also redirect to remove all trailing slashes (*ALL*, whether an existing directory, the bare domain name `example.com`, etc). This was in a previous iteration of my htaccess file, but I removed it because it was creating an infinite redirect loop on `example.com/khp`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `/khp` is a real directory and `mod_dir` runs after `mod_rewrite` and adds a trailing slash in the rewritten URI.

To turn this behavior off use:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# everything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/khp/handler.php
RewriteRule (.*) /khp/handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

# add a trailing slash to directories via a rule
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: It seems to work, even though your code says it's adding a trailing slash to the directories? Why is that?

Comment: That last rule is optional, good-to-have since not having a trailing slash in front of a directory can list directory content if default index file is not present and is considered a security risk.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have directory browsing disabled. And it shouldn't do anything if everything redirects to the handler already, right?

Comment: Yes in that case you can skip last rule if directory browsing is disabled.